# Ionic radio-group with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on a project in Ionic and need to use reactive forms from Angular 5.  I need to allow a user to select a language preference and I'm doing that with radio-group and ion-radio, but when I make changes to the form, I'm getting

```
ERROR Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'preferredLanguage'
```

Here is my template with the form

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>User Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form *ngIf="user" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Display Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="displayName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="firstName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Last Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="lastName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Street</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="street"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>City</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="city"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>State</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="state"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Zip Code</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="zip"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-list radio-group formControlName="preferredLanguage">
        <ion-list-header>
          Select Preferred Language
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>English</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="en-US"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Spanish</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="es-US"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    <button type="submit" ion-button>Submit Profile</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Here is my method that initializes the form

```
initProfileForm() {
    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      displayName: [this.user.profile.displayName, Validators.required],
      firstName: [this.user.profile.firstName, Validators.required],
      lastName: [this.user.profile.lastName, Validators.required],
      email: [this.user.profile.email, Validators.required],
      street: [this.user.profile.street, Validators.required],
      city: [this.user.profile.city, Validators.required],
      state: [this.user.profile.state, Validators.required],
      zip: [this.user.profile.zip, Validators.required] ,
      preferredLanguage: [this.user.profile.preferredLanguage, 
Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Has anyone else had this issue and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up coming up with a solution.  This blog helped me come up with an answer: https://robferguson.org/blog/2017/11/19/ionic-3-and-forms/   Apparently, radio-group doesn't work with formControlName so instead I ended up using this:

```
  <ion-list radio-group [formControl]="profileForm.controls['preferredLanguage']">
    <ion-list-header>
      Select Preferred Language
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>English</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="en-US"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Spanish</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="es-US"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

This fixed the issue so there is no longer an error.

Answer (score 1):

Make some amendments in your HTML code:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>English</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="en-US" formControlName="preferredLanguage"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Spanish</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="es-US" formControlName="preferredLanguage"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
```

So basically instead of using it on parent use it individually for each radio button. This worked for me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have the exact problem using "ion-radio-group" with ionic 4. the best solution is to avoid it and use a list instead.

Comment: This doesn't work because the value that the 'preferredLanguage' ends up getting, is "true", it doesn't pass the radio's attribute along. If your form creation file is different from standard you need to past it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
get preferredLanguage() {
  return this.profileForm.get('preferredLanguage').value;
}

set preferredLanguage(ev: CustomEvent) {
  this.profileForm.get('preferredLanguage').patchValue(ev.detail.value);
}
```

```html
<ion-radio-group [value]="preferredLanguage" (ionChange)="preferredLanguage = $event">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>English</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="en-US"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Spanish</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="es-US"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers didn't work for me and I had to revert back to using [(ngModel)] and setting the item manually. The suggestions of moving to ion-list or ion-row seemed to make the situation worse not better. This with Ionic 4.

```
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="controlValue" ngDefaultControl [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ionChange)="setControlValue($event)">
```

Declare your model variable:

```
  eventId: string = '';
```

Set it in initialisation if you need to. And when changed set the form control:

```
  setControlValue($event){
    this.myForm.controls['controlValue'].setValue($event?.detail?.value);
  }
```

On the form ngDefaultControl is needed otherwise you will get form issues and the model options indicate that you want to use the legacy ngModel approach and dont issue the error you are mixing both forms.