# Radio buttons in ngForm - cant get value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<form #reservationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createReservation(reservationForm)">
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding" *ngFor="let item of items.services | keyvalue">
    <ion-radio value="{{item.key}}" class="ion-no-margin" name="itemRadio" ngModel></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
</form>
```

module.ts:

```
  createReservation(formData: NgForm) {
    console.log(formData.value);
  }
```

1. I get only:

```
] [console.log]: {
[ng]   "item": true
[ng] }
```

2. I can select all of 10 radios... (should select only 1).

Where's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic radio-group with Angular Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948838/ionic-radio-group-with-angular-reactive-forms)

Comment: Hello Daniel, i dont use form builders. im importing only ngform. Should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.

1. Delete ngModel from radiobutton.
2. Add ngModel to

```
<ion-radio-group allow-empty-selection="false" name="radioGroup" ngModel name="radioGroup">
```

then

```
console.log(reservationForm.value);
```